# how to select all list items except for the first and last using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-selectors

I have an HTML list, from which I need to select all but the first and last element.

Right now I'm trying like this:

```
.inputList li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    // stuff
    }
```

Not really working... is there a better way, that also works on IE?

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a declaration for *all* child elements, then *override* it for first and last children:

```css
.example > LI {background: green; }

.example > LI:first-child,
.example > LI:last-child {background: none; }
```

Comment: yup. I guess this is the way to go. THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

Write like this:

```
.inputList li:first-child, .inputList li:last-child{
  color:red;
}
```

Note `:first-child` work till IE7 & above. `:last-child` work till IE9 & above.

Comment: I need all BUT the first and last element.

Answer (score 4):

First element can be ignored as

```
li + li{border-left: 1px solid #000;}
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found another way to do this so just posting it for documentation sake:

```css
.inputList li + li:not(:last-child) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

In my case I wanted it to put a comma after the list-item

```css
.education li:not(:last-child):after {
        content: ",";
      }
```